# Python Activation Issues

Tags: python

I'm geting this issue, can't run my scripts, although they work in AREPL.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\luke_\OneDrive\Desktop\Python> & c:/Users/luke_/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
& : File C:\Users\luke_\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on    
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
 & c:/Users/luke_/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS C:\Users\luke_\OneDrive\Desktop\Python> & c:/Users/luke_/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/luke_/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/luke_/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/example.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
PS C:\Users\luke_\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>
```

Comment: You need to install `requests` module. Run `pip install requests`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the required modules to run the script,
open up the command line and run:

`pip install requests`

and it should fix the issue - if there are no other modules missing.